# IPV6 Bind/DNS DHCP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ipv6, dhcp-server

We are run the one event in that there 7000 people are visiting, with Laptop to provide then internet access.

We thought of setting up IPV6 DNS/DHCP all this people will be use LAN cable to get connected to Linux Server (centos/RHEL/Fedora) that will be connected to switch.

Question is we are not able setup DNS /DHCP using IPV6 if any one has done this kind of configuration kindly share the step by step implementation plan it will really appreciate.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1:

- make sure you have production-quality IPv6 connectivity

Step 2:

- configure your routers/firewalls

Step 3:

- let your routers/firewalls send out RAs (Router Advertisements)

  - advertise not-managed, no-other-configuration
  - advertise the routed prefix with (a)utoconfiguration flag enabled

Now you already have IPv6 connectivity. You don't need DHCPv6 because you use SLAAC (Stateless Auto Configuration) and DNS requests still go over IPv4, but connectivity is there.

Step 4:

- configure a stateless DHCPv6 server

  - advertise IPv6 DNS resolvers
  - if your ISP doesn't provide them you can use the public Google DNS resolvers (see http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html)
- change the RAs

  - Set the other-configuration flag so the clients know that there is a stateless DHCPv6 server

How to exactly configure everything depends on the hardware and software you use. You didn't specify that so I can't help you with the details...

Comment: and if you can, filter out any RAs accidentally (or otherwise) spewed out by your clients...

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick solution for our issues. Internet link got IPV4 address on Cisco Router -->Linux (centos 6.2-DHCPD/DNS)eth0-->eth1-->switch--->7000 user will get they ethX via cat 6 cable.

Comment: If your internet link doesn't have IPv6 then don't offer it to your clients. It will only cause trouble because they *will* then try to connect to the internet with IPv6.